# Error with Fabricjs and Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, fabricjs

I develop an application in Fabric.js to create your own helmet design and view in a 3D model (with Three.js).

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but when I try to work in Internet Explorer 11, sometimes it crashes when I add an image from url.

I have some big canvas (5000+ x 7000+ px) loaded in memory to create final print image, but user works in small canvas (380 x 340 px).

When I load a big image (5000+ px scaled to see properly in small canvas) sometimes It works, and sometimes crashes in function render:

```
_render: function(ctx) {
    this._element && ctx.drawImage(
                       this._element,
                       -this.width / 2,
                       -this.height / 2,
                       this.width,
                       this.height
                     );
```

with "Not specified error".

And finally, it never works when I get small canvas objects and copy it to big canvas to generate final big print file, with same error.

The url to test it is http://www.3dhelmetsnzi.com/v2/home.php (select one model and size) and test it if you want.

Could someone tell me what could be the problem?